# Error while creating a workflow

Tags: workflow, document-library, workflow-activity

I was creating a workflow and all went well up to receiving the e-mail.

After receiving the mail, I tried to open the task but then the following warning message appeared on the screen:

[image]

**So my questions are:**

1. What could be the possible reason?

2. And what steps shall I follow now to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open Internet Explorer.
- Go to Internet Options.
- Under the Security tab, Click on the Sites Button. Add “*.yourdomain.com” to the trusted sites list.
- Click Close.